# Disable close dropdown after click href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to keep my `dropdown` opened after a page load. For example if I click on an `item(href)` into an `dropdown`, I would like to keep the `dropdown` opened after the redirection.

I've seen that there is a method jquery named `stopPropagation`, but it seems that this does not work for me

HTML

```
<div class="sidenav">
  <div class="item_sn">
    Groups
  </div> 
  <div class="item_list_body">
    <div class="link_sidenav">
      <a href="#" class="sub_item">
        group 1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="link_sidenav">
        <a href="#" class="sub_item">
          group 2
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item_sn">
    Users
  </div> 
  <div class="item_list_body">
    <div class="link_sidenav">
      <a href="#" class="sub_item">
        user 1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="link_sidenav">
        <a href="#" class="sub_item">
          user 2
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.item_list_body').hide();
    $('.item_sn').on('click', function (event) {
      var content = $(this).next('.item_list_body')
      content.slideToggle();
      $('.item_list_body').not(content).slideUp();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Solution 1 (not working) :

```
$(document).on('click', '.sub_item', function (e) {
  $(this).parent('.link_sidenav').parent('.item_list_body').toggle();
});
```

Comment: `stopPropagation()` is javascript... also you can try `preventDefault()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `sessionStorage` to store the state of the menu and then open the menu on page load by checking the state see below

---

**EDIT**

rather than using state of the menu we should save the index of the clicked menu as discussed in the comment so updated my answer

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    //sessionStorage.removeItem('opened');
    $('.item_list_body').hide();
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('opened') !== null) {
        $('.sidenav>div:eq(' + sessionStorage.getItem('opened') + ')').next('.item_list_body').show();
    }

    $('.item_sn').on('click', function (event) {
        var content = $(this).next('.item_list_body');
        var elem = $(this);

        content.slideDown(0, function () {
            sessionStorage.setItem('opened', elem.index());
        });
        $('.item_list_body').not(content).slideUp();
    });
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MuhammadOmerAslam, it looks a good solution in my case, I'm on it.

Comment: Thanks, It looks good, but the only problem is that when I open one of my dropdowns and I click on an Item, after reload, all the dropdown are opened. I'm trying to solve it but if you have an other advice, I'll be very happy !!

Comment: yeah sure, but can you add the relevant `Css` for the dropdown in your OP

Comment: Thanks a lot, well I don't have any css for the moment. At this time I just have 2 dropdown Into my sidenav.

Comment: and you might need to add the complete `html` of your menu as i dont get what you mean by all the menus are opened do you have multiple Groups Menus? thats ok if there isnt any `css`

Comment: Yeap, exactly as you say. I made an edit of my post to give you better explanation. That's why I have  a function .not in my js, to close the other menu.

Comment: i updated the answer it should work perfectly now just checked on my local machine @stigGaret

Comment: Cool !! Thanks you  so much for your help @MuhammadOmerAslam. You're a boss !! I've now a better understanding of how SessionStorage work. It will be so useful for other stuff in my app. Thanks again, have a good continuation.

Comment: that was a bit too much for me glad it helped you out in sorting the problem.you can get a good understanding regarding the `sessionStorage` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), be good.